# Pydantic to load list of nested json objects thows missing value

Tags: python, pydantic

I have the following pydantic objects:

```
class NestedObject(BaseModel):
    id: int

class MainObject(BaseModel):
    id: int
    nested_objects: list[NestedObject]
```

Also I have a JSON string that I want pydantic to build the objects from:

```
bla = """
{
    "id": 1,
    "nested_objects:": [
        {
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2
        }
    ]
}
"""
```

How I load my json string:

```
MainObject.model_validate_json(bla)
```

When I try to load the JSON string with the model, it gives me a [ValidationError](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.6/errors/validation_errors/#missing) saying that `nested_objects` are missing.

I have been scratching my head over this, since I couldn't find anything in the documentation stating that it is not possible to validate from complex nested json structures.

Do I need a field_validator in order to make this work, or have I missed something?

Comment: hi! which version of pydantic are you using?

Comment: it looks like you have an errant colon where you intended to have "nested_objects" (and pydantic did its job)

Comment: it indeed looks like I have......... thanks for being my extra pair of eyes.